# Python(3): TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

so I am making a game that is basically just a Pokemon clone. It is very small compared to the actual game. I am making it for practice, and I keep on getting an error when trying to implement damage. It's on line 148-158. I don't know what is wrong, I've tried doing `str()` and `int()`, but those don't work. I know that `firefox1` is supposed to have a number assigned to it, as well as `waterblast`, but It won't let me subtract them. I am very sorry if it's messy, I am new and just experimenting with code all the time. Thank you very much for taking your time to help me, If you need more info a will try to reply when I can.

```
#Python Project - Pokemon Clone - Game name: Pokymon

import time
import random
def health1():
    health1 = random.randint(20,50)
    return "This Pokymon is level 1, their health is " + str(health1)
    
one = health1()

def health2():
    health2 = random.randint(50,80)
    return "This Pokymon is level 2, their health is " + str(health2)

two = health2()


def health3():
    health3 = random.randint(80,120)
    return "This Pokymon is level 3, their health is " + str(health3)
    
three = health3()

def health4():
    health4 = random.randint(120,160)
    return "This Pokymon is level 4, their health is " + str(health4)
    
four = health4()

def health5():
    health5 = random.randint(160,180)
    return "This Pokymon is level 5, their health is " + str(health5)
    
five = health5()

def health6():
    health6 = random.randint(180,220)
    return "This Pokymon is level 6, their health is " + str(health6)
    
six = health6()

def health7():
    health7 = random.randint(220,260)
    return "This Pokymon is level 7, their health is " + str(health7)
    
seven = health7()

def health8():
    health8 = random.randint(260,300)
    return "This Pokymon is level 8, their health is " + str(health8)
    
eight = health8()

def health9():
    health9 = random.randint(300,340)
    return "This Pokymon is level 9, their health is " + str(health9)
    
nine = health9()

def health10():
    health10 = random.randint(340,380)
    return "This Pokymon is level 10, their health is " + str(health10)
    
ten = health10()

def boss():
    boss = random.randint(450,620)
    return "The boss's health is " + str(boss)
    
boss = boss()

def firefox1():
    firefox1 = random.choice([one, two, three, four, five])
    return "You encountered a firefox! " + str(firefox1)
    
def waterbat1():
    waterbat1 = random.choice([one, two, three, four, five])
    return "You encountered a waterbat! " + str(waterbat1)
    
def sandcat1():
    sandcat1 = random.choice([one, two, three, four, five])
    return "You encountered a sandcat! " + str(sandcat1)
    
def wagtail1():
    wagtail1 = random.choice([one, two, three, four, five])
    return "You encountered a wagtail! " + str(wagtail1)
    
def magmast1():
    magmast1 = boss
    return "You encountered the boss Magmast! You now have to fight him in order to go to the next island." + str(magmast1)

def waterfox():
    waterfox = onehealth1
    return "This is your new pokymon, " + str(waterfox)

def firefalcon():
    firefalcon = onehealth1
    return "This is your new pokymon, " + str(firefalcon)
    
def rockyram():
    rockyram = onehealth1
    return "This is your new pokymon, " + str(rockyram)

def windywallaby():
    windywallaby = onehealth1
    return "This is your new pokymon, " + str(windywallaby)

def onehealth1():
    onehealth1 = random.randint(20,50)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 1, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth1)

def onehealth2():
    onehealth2 = random.randint(50,80)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 2, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth2)

def onehealth3():
    onehealth3 = random.randint(80,120)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 3, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth3)

def onehealth4():
    onehealth4 = random.randint(120,160)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 4, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth4)

def onehealth5():
    onehealth5 = random.randint(160,180)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 5, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth5)

def onehealth6():
    onehealth6 = random.randint(180,220)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 6, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth6)

def onehealth7():
    onehealth7 = random.randint(220,260)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 7, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth7)

def onehealth8():
    onehealth8 = random.randint(260,300)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 8, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth8)

def onehealth9():
    onehealth9 = random.randint(300,340)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 9, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth9)

def onehealth10():
    onehealth10 = random.randint(340,380)
    return "Your Pokymon's level is 10, and your Pokymon's health is " + str(onehealth10)

def waterblast():
    waterblast = 20
    return waterblast

def damage1(firefox1, waterblast):
    damage1 = firefox1() - waterblast()
    return "This pokymon now has " + str(damage1)

attack = input(firefox1() + " " + "Attack: ").lower().strip()
if attack == "Waterblast".casefold():
    print(str(damage1(firefox1, waterblast)))
```

Comment: which line of code you are receiving this error?

Comment: The method `firefox1()` returns a `str`, the method `waterblast()` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line when you call dammage1(), you're passing a string with firefox1() and an int with waterblast()